# How can I use Devilspie2 to bring a window to the foreground when opened?

Tags: window-manager, window

I try to bring the [Lollypop](https://gnumdk.github.io/lollypop-web/) main window to the foreground (front) when opened, using [Devilspie2](http://www.gusnan.se/devilspie2/manual.php).

I use the following code in `config.lua`:

```
if (get_window_class()=="Lollypop") then
    unmaximize();
    focus();
    focus_window();
end
```

However, as you can see below, Lollypop is opened in the background.

[image: GIF animation]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `get_window_class()` is the correct function for your problem, try it with `get_window_name()` or `get_application_name()`:

```
if (get_window_name()=="Lollypop") then
  unmaximize();
  focus();
  focus_window(); 
end
```

Or run devilspie2 in the terminal and check with `debug_print(get_window_class())` what that returns.